# Use mergeWith of Lodash with nested objects

Tags: javascript, merge, lodash

I have two objects like that:

```
const object1 = {first: [{a: 0, b:3}], second: [{a: 1, b:2}], third: [{a: 3, b:2}]}
const object2 = {first: [{a: 1, b:0}], second: [{a: 10, b:0}], third: [{a: 2, b:3}]}
```

and I want the sum of these two objects:

```
const res = {first: [{a: 1, b:3}], second: [{a: 11, b:2}], third: [{a: 5, b:5}]}
```

I tried to use mergeWith of Lodash in this way:

```
const res = mergeWith({}, object1, object2, add)
```

but I get:

```
{first: NaN, second: NaN, third: NaN}
```

How can I use mergeWith with nested objects?

Comment: What is the `add` function doing?

Comment: Is the add function of Lodash

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't realist you were importing the functions separately. In that case it won't work, since it would try to add an *array* to another array which results in `NaN`, as you see.

Comment: @vlaz Ok, any tips to solve?

Comment: Are you always going to have a single object within the array? As I mean the `first: [{a: 0, b:3}]` - if you could have two entries in the array, then the merge logic could be more complicated. Or maybe not - if you expect to merge matching indeces.

Comment: Wait, I'm overthinking it... `mergeWith` is doing a recursive merge down and actually handles that for you. Hold on, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When doing [`mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/#mergeWith) you need to pass a customizer. Lodash then does a recursive merging of values.

The trick is that if your customizer returns `undefined`, then `merge` is used to combine the values. However, since `add` returns `NaN` for incompatible values, that value is used instead - so if you merely have a function that works like `add` but returns `undefined` instead of `NaN`, then `mergeWith` will do all the heavy lifting for you:

```js
const object1 = {first: [{a: 0, b:3}], second: [{a: 1, b:2}], third: [{a: 3, b:2}]}
const object2 = {first: [{a: 1, b:0}], second: [{a: 10, b:0}], third: [{a: 2, b:3}]}

const res = _.mergeWith({}, object1, object2, customizer)

console.log(res);

function customizer(a, b) {
  // you can still use add
  const result = _.add(a, b);
  
  // ignore NaN values and return undefined instead
  if (_.isNaN(result)) { 
    return;
  }
  
  //only combine values that can be combined
  return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

An alternative shorter way to express this is by using [`defaultTo`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#defaultTo)

```js
const object1 = {first: [{a: 0, b:3}], second: [{a: 1, b:2}], third: [{a: 3, b:2}]}
const object2 = {first: [{a: 1, b:0}], second: [{a: 10, b:0}], third: [{a: 2, b:3}]}

const customizer = (a, b) => _.defaultTo(_.add(a, b), undefined)

const res = _.mergeWith({}, object1, object2, customizer)

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining how to add the objects did the trick:

```
const res = mergeWith(object1, object2, (objValue, srcValue) =>
    [{
        a: objValue[0].a + srcValue[0].a,
        b: objValue[0].b + srcValue[0].b
    }]
)
```